# SEVERE: Context Initialization failed java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application]

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a Spring MVC app basing it on this tutorial : http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-hibernate-maven-crud/

I keep having this same error.

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class:         org.example.app.init.WebAppConfig; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application] cannot be opened because it does not exist at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289)
```

I initially suspected it might have something to do with WebAppConfig.java where I have :

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") 
public class WebAppConfig {
```

I tried to look at other questions that were answered on StackOverflow but I  haven't found a solution. I am using j2ee eclipse and Tomcat 7.0.41.

***UPDATE*** (I *think* I solved it)

It's really strange. All of a sudden the issue isn't there anymore. It *might* have been because I went to 'server.xml' in the Tomcat folder and commented out the line below.

```
<Context docBase="spr-mav-mvc" path="/spr-mav-mvc" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:spr-mav-mvc"/>
```

The unfortunate thing is I still have no real idea as to what the problem was and the solution itself.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `"class path resource [application] cannot be opened because it does not exist"` .

Spring framework is trying to find `"application"` instead of `"application.properties"`.
Please double check if `@PropertySource` has `classpath:application.properties`.

Comment: Yeah I rechecked and it seemed okay. I seemed to have found a solution and I noted the details in my original question.